# Impossible to navigate to a related contentNote in custom Lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, contentnote

I'm building a 'simple' component that displays a list of notes related to a `collaborationGroup`.  Basic functionality works.  I am unable to make the note title into a link, and just discovered tha both [force:navigateToSObject](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_force_navigateToSObject.htm) and [force:navigateToURL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_force_navigateToURL.htm) do not support contentNote

> URLs corresponding to ContentNote SObjects aren’t supported.
>
> Record IDs corresponding to ContentNote SObjects aren’t supported.

Is there a workaround?  Is there some other reasonably close option, like navigating to a list of notes?  Or some way to pop open a note in the notes app in the utility bar?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?